# How To Change Button Style?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have this button:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="EXIT" Style="{StaticResource RedButton}" />
```

and its style:

```
<Style x:Key="RedButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">                
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">                        
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                            
                </Grid>                        
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>                
    </Setter>            
</Style>
```

But all it does it complain, on the button: "Cannot resolve TargetName Border"

I'm trying to style the pressed visual state for the button. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run the app? Is this WP8 or WP8.1?

Comment: It is 8.1. When I run it it breaks in App.gi.cs (app.xaml hold the styles)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following link for customization of your button using a ControlTemplate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903963%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML code In the Pressed State you are trying to modify a target called Border. The problem is that in your grid there is no such element. There is not border added to the grid nor there is a property called border available for a grid. And when you go to edit current template, it only shows a grid. There are nothing inside the grid. My advice is to discard the current style and create a new one. No need to mess with XAML because you can easily get this done using Blend for VS.

Try this tutorial, Explains from beginning to end how to customize a Button Style.
http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/custom-xaml-controllers-i-adding-custom-styles-to-elements/

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously no Border element to apply the color to.

What happens if you create a style like this one:

```
<Style x:Key="RedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```